# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND epg_data.start'' ORDER BY epg_data.start DESC' at line 6

Tags: php, mysql

Hi All I Keep Getting This Error its to load a page quite a simple one i cant work out what it is i know it says it but i am stumped any help would be greatly appreciated

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND epg_data.start'' ORDER BY epg_data.start DESC' at line 6

```
 $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT streams.id, epg_data.lang, epg_data.start, epg_data.end, epg_data.description, streams_sys.stream_status, streams.stream_display_name, streams.stream_icon, epg_data.title AS epg_title
    FROM ((streams_sys
    LEFT JOIN streams ON streams.id=streams_sys.stream_id)
    RIGHT JOIN epg_data ON epg_data.channel_id=streams.channel_id)
    WHERE streams.id=".$_GET["id"]."
AND epg_data.start<NOW()
AND epg_data.end>'".$_GET["time"]."'
ORDER BY epg_data.start DESC";
```

Comment: Debugging tip: print out the actual query *after* you've put those variables in (e.g. `echo $query_Recordset1`) and you'll quickly find your problem. (My guess would be that `$_GET["id"]` returns nothing, but it's only a guess without seeing your actual SQL.) Also: your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared queries with actual parameters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementations

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your `$_GET["id"]` has no value, and your SQL statement ended up containing this error:

```
...WHERE streams.id=  AND epg_data.start<NOW()...
```

This is a syntax error of course.

Do yourself a huge favor and stop interpolating variables into SQL queries. It's insecure with respect to SQL Injection, and more to the point it's too difficult.

Use query parameters instead:

```
$query_Recordset1 = "
SELECT streams.id, epg_data.lang, epg_data.start, epg_data.end,
 epg_data.description, streams_sys.stream_status, streams.stream_display_name, 
 streams.stream_icon, epg_data.title AS epg_title
FROM ((streams_sys
LEFT JOIN streams ON streams.id=streams_sys.stream_id)
RIGHT JOIN epg_data ON epg_data.channel_id=streams.channel_id)
WHERE streams.id=?
AND epg_data.start<NOW()
AND epg_data.end>?
ORDER BY epg_data.start DESC";
```

See? It's so much easier. No more need to give yourself eyestrain wondering if you closed the inner or the outer quotes correctly. Just use `?` in place of the variable. 
Do not try to put quotes around the `?`. It doesn't matter if your parameters are numeric, string, or date.

Then prepare and execute:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query_Recordset1);
$stmt->execute([$_GET["id"], $_GET["time"]]);
```

Using query parameters is easier and safer. You'll thank yourself for switching to using query parameters!

Note that parameters can be used only in a place where you would normally use a constant value. You cannot use parameters for table names, column names, SQL keywords, or other expressions. Only where you would use a single literal value like a number, quoted string, or quoted date.

Comment: "Query parameters" better known as -> "Prepared Statements". Just in case he was trying to search for more info on them. Good start: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Randall I say "query parameters" to be more specific, because one can prepare() and execute() an SQL statement that contains no parameters. But you're right, one needs to use prepare() and execute() if the query contains parameters.

Comment: Either way, hopefully knowing to prepare now will help the question asker out :)